# Java: inicializar solamente un valor en un hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Tengo este hashmap: `private HashMap<String, Integer> userMoney = new HashMap<>();` y quiero que el "Integer" tenga de default 100, no quiero usar el .put porque a fuerzas necesito especificarle un String (  elhashmap.put("oscar",100) ) y quiero que el Hashmap se inicialize para cualquier String, no solo para uno en concreto

Pensé que algo así me serviria pero al parecer no:
`private HashMap<String, Integer> userMoney = new HashMap<>(100);`

Comment: No creo que eso se pueda hacer tal como intentas... pero qué problema hay en insertar un 100 hardcodeado siempre que insertes algo?? No lo entiendo. En el método desde el que vas a insertar simplemente pones el `100` en el put y listo.

Comment: porque cuando en algun momento de mi programa use el .put, quiero que el hashmap ya tenga un valor definido en el Integer (PARA TODOS LOS "USUARIOS/Strings"). Como si en la vida real te creas una cuenta de banco( hashmap.put("nombre",0) ) pero el banco te regala $100 dolares

Comment: El valor por defecto de un int, es 0. El de un Integer sin declarar null. Esos son los únicos valores *"por defecto"* que vas a tener si quieres usar los tipos que te da Java, puesto que esos valores los definieron ellos. Si quieres otro comportamiento, te recomiendo que uses una clase propia tuya, haciendo por ejemplo un `HashMap<String, User>`, y al `User` le puedes definir los campos que quieras, con los valores que quieras.

Comment: perdon si no me di a entender jaja, quiero que todos los int DEL HASHMAP sean por defecto 100, ademas con "user" me refiero al String que usé en el hashmap(HashMap<String,Integer> el String es el usuario, el Integer del hashmap es lo que quiero cambiar de default de 0 a 100)

Comment: Si no vas a usar el `put` o el `putAll` ¿Qué vas a usar? No hay otra forma  de agregar valores a un `HashMap`. Al poner un elemento en el HashMap, ponlo con valor inicial con 100. Así de simple. Tu pregunta no tiene ni pies ni cabeza. No puedes ni siquiera tener elementos sin clave, ni puedes agregar elementos sin valor.

Comment: esta bien, gracias de todas formas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Además de la respuesta de Sal, algo que puedes hacer es definir un método que lo haga por defecto

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> users;
    private static final Integer DEFAULT_VALUE = 100;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        users = new HashMap<>();
        addToHashMap("Fernando", "Daniela", "Ulises");
        users.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
    }

    public static void addToHashMap(String... keys) {
        for (String key : keys)
            users.put(key, DEFAULT_VALUE);
    }

}
```

En este código se usaron variables de clase, pero puedes adaptarlo para pasarle el hashmap por argumento, o cambiar el default value en el argumento de la misma forma

**Resultados**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eduardo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, en este preciso caso me ha servido mas la respuesta de Sal pero la tuya la aprecio mucho y tambien me ayuda a comprender mas los HashMap :)

Answer (score 0):

Considera que el primer `put` te regresa `null`.
Una clase excéntrica:

```
public class MoneyHashMap extends HashMap<String,Integer>{
   
   private Integer inicial;
   
   public MoneyHashMap(Integer inicial){
      super();
      this.inicial = inicial;
   }
   
   @Override
   public Integer put(String key, Integer value){
      Integer valorAnterior = super.put(key, value);
      if( valorAnterior == null ){
         super.put(key, value+inicial);
         return inicial;
      }
      return valorAnterior;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args){
      MoneyHashMap mhm = new MoneyHashMap(100);
      mhm.put("u1",10);
      mhm.put("u2",20);
      
      System.out.println(" "+mhm);
   }
   
}
```

Resultado:

```
 {u1=110, u2=120}
```

Comment: Sal, para este caso me ha servido mucho tu método. Gracias!